# jquery loaded, but not executing proper UI function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a validation script, and I'm tying to check if the first name field is left blank. I originally just changed the background color of the field and that worked, but now I want to use jquery to fade in a highlight. This is the code so far.

```
var x = document.forms['getinfo']['fname'].value;
var validated = true;
if (x==null || x =="") { 
    //document.getElementById('trfname').style.background="#FF9999";
    document.getElementById('trfname').style.borderRadius = '7px';
    $("trfname").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
    validated = false;
}
```

As you can see I commented out the old javascript code that worked and I'm trying to use the jquery highlight function. It's not working and I was wondering if anyone had some input. I've checked if Jquery loads properly and it does, so it's not that. I also included the jquery-ui library, to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for an element named `trfname`, not an id. Add the missing `#`.

```
$("#trfname").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = $('form[name="getinfo"] input[name="fname"]').val();
var validated = true;
if (x.length < 1) { 
    $('#trfname').css('border-radius', '7px').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
    validated = false;
}
```